# Issue with writing a query from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a query for homework, but there is one query in particular that I am having trouble with. The one that I am having trouble with is supposed to get all forms of government 
from a table, and then get the count of how many countries have that form of government. 
I understand I would have to use the count function, but I don't understand how I would
add 1 for each time  government is mentioned. Also, the independent year thing is confusing me too. Here is the exact definition of the query

> Generate a list of all forms of government with the count of how many
>   countries have that form of government. Also, list the most recent
>   year in which any country became independent with that   form of
>   government. The results should be ordered by decreasing count.

Here is the code that I tried, along with the table that I tried

```
SELECT government_form, COUNT(government_form) AS count, indep_year 
FROM what.country
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Here is the table that I am using

```
               Table "what.country"
     Column      |         Type          |               Modifiers              
-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------
 country_code    | character(3)          | not null default ''::bpchar
 name            | character varying(52) | not null default ''::character varying
 continent       | continent             | not null
 region          | character varying(26) | not null default ''::character varying
 surface_area    | real                  | not null default 0::real
 indep_year      | smallint              | 
 population      | integer               | not null default 0
 life_expectancy | real                  | 
 gnp             | real                  | 
 gnp_old         | real                  | 
 local_name      | character varying(45) | not null default ''::character varying
 government_form | character varying(45) | not null default ''::character varying
```

Comment: You're doing  CMP_SC 3380 at Missouri with @ryan, right?

Answer (score 2):

> Generate a list of all forms of government with the count of how many
>   countries have that form of government. Also, list the most recent
>   year in which any country became independent with that form of
>   government. The results should be ordered by decreasing count.

First lets understand the question in parts

> count of how many countries have that form of government

means we need to `GROUP BY` `government_form` and then apply `COUNT` on `countries`

> most recent year in which any country became independent with that form of
>   government

means we need to also find `MAX` `indep_year` after grouping by  `government_form`

Thus the query is

```
SELECT government_form, COUNT(countries) AS count, MAX(indep_year)
FROM what.country
GROUP BY government_form
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: My personal opinion is that for homework it's best not to give the complete query; the explanation you gave is excellent and should be sufficient to let the person write the query its self themselves.

Comment: I agree. The policy I followed so far is if the OP don't post any attempts to solve the question I answer it partly. If OP posts his attempts, I try to give a complete answer. Should I edit it now?

Comment: It's entirely down to your judgment. I don't see that there's any need to edit (and anyway, the edit history is public). I just wanted to check that you'd thought about it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I will keep it in mind for next time.